# Bootstrap circular responsive images not adjusting to be within same circle size

Tags: css, html, image, twitter-bootstrap

I would like a row of three evenly sized circles to appear within my Bootstrap team section. Instead, the circles currently are different sizes depending on the ground truth images, which means the text below the circles (profile pictures) is also not starting at the same line on the webpage.

http://www.bootply.com/LaIxZFaQLO

Any idea what I can do to ensure the circles are always exactly the same size and adjust according to the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure all your images are the same width and height from the get go, then all it would look like is this (no extra css)

http://www.bootply.com/ebWjKhRsN2

OR

You will have to make them all the same size via css

```
.team-member img {
   width: 330px;
   height: 330px;
}
```

when you resize the screen, then you'll have to adjust the height and make it the same as the width via media queries

e.g (in medium sized screens, the width will be 220px, so:

```
/* md */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
     .team-member img {
        height: 220px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found resizing the images before to be much easier, but this is good to know as didn't know about media queries.